# Inserting a section title into a header with titlesec and fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec

I would like to place specially formatted section titles into page headers. I had been accomplishing this with `titlesec` and `fancyhdr`. However, after updating my tex distribution my solution no longer works. The code compiles but the section titles do not appear in the header or anywhere.

I've posted a minimal example below. Switching between the 2 `titleformat` commands demonstrates the issue. If I place the format code inside an `lhead` the section titles disappear.

If you have any insight into why this occurring or have an alternative solution I would greatly appreciate it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Support for header customization
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Customize title and sections headers
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% Clear page headers and footers. 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

% Section Header customization
% Comment/Uncomment to see issue.
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0em}{\lhead{ \Large\sffamily #1 }} 
% \titleformat{\section}{}{}{0em}{\Large\sffamily #1}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section Label}

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You want no number for your sections?

Comment: Correct, I would like the section titles to appear without the section number.

Comment: But how would you make cross references?

Comment: The use case for this was generating presentations. I haven't had the need to cross reference slides. I'm basically indifferent to the presence of numbers. If there's a solution that includes numbers it would still help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you want? I used the companion package `titleps`:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{titleps}

    \titleformat{\section}{}{}{0em}{\lhead{ \Large\sffamily #1 }}
     \titleformat{\section}{}{}{0em}{\Large\sffamily #1}

    \usepackage{titleps}
    \newpagestyle{mine}{\headrule
    \sethead[][\sffamily\sectiontitle][]{}{\sffamily\sectiontitle}{}%

    \setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}}

    \pagestyle{mine}
    \begin{document}

        \section{Section Label}

        \lipsum[1-6]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That functionality is very helpful.

Comment: @Michael! You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!